# "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://0.0.0.0/socket.io/1/?t=1396276017188. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header" on Nitrous.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, nitrousio

I have found multiple solutions to this problem, but none of them seem to work for Nitrous.io. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That url doesn't look right.  Are you really trying to connect to the `socket.io` servers?

Comment: I actually pasted it wrong and forgot the 0.0.0.0

Comment: Why are you using `0.0.0.0`?  That doesn't sound like its going to go well.  What domain is the html page on?

Comment: I'm running my app on Nitrous.io, instead of localhost the app is bound to 0.0.0.0

Comment: Binding to `0.0.0.0` makes it available publicly (instead of only on the loopback address) but it is _not_ the ip you use to locate it.  It has a special meaning.  You should be navigating to `127.0.0.1` or, preferably, your hostname.